# Make sql where clause prioritize one prefix-like-search above another

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an sql table with some nvarchar columns, lets call them 'Title' and 'Value'.

I currently use a linqtosql query to make a prefix search to find rows in this table, like so

```
var result = from _item in GetTable()
    where _item.Title.StartsWith( "hello" ) || _item.Value.StartsWith( "hello" )
    select _item;
return result.Take( 100 );
```

which generates the corresponing sql:

```
@p0=N'hello%'
@p1=N'hello%'
SELECT TOP (100) *
FROM [Table] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Title] LIKE @p0) OR ([t0].[Value] LIKE @p1)
```

which works somewhat, but lets say I want to prioritize the Value column over the Title column. ie if the _item.Value.StartsWith constraint returns 100 results, only those are returned. If it returns 25 results, the remaining 75 are filled from the 'Title' constraint.

I could do it using several queries, but that could fill my result set with duplicate entries.

Can this be done in linqtosql or do I have to manually write an sql query to fix it? In either case, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add an `ORDER BY`? (Don't know how to do this in linq)

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [t0].[Value] LIKE @p1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: I just store the sql in a function and call that function from linq. Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: How can I distinct my query with this ORDER BY case? SQL Server is throwing an error: `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Comment: @WillemdeWit Either use a `GROUP BY <all selected columns>` instead of `DISTINCT` or do the `DISTINCT` inside a CTE or derived table including the ordering expression then select from that all columns except the ordering expression without using `DISTINCT` at the outer level.